# Gatsby / Drupal8 decouple: How do I render an image on a Gatsby page that pulls from a Drupal file directory?

Tags: image, drupal, graphql, drupal-8, gatsby

GOAL: use Gatsby to render Drupal 8 images associated with nodes

I can render the default Drupal 8 Article node info just fine using a GraphQL query. I cannot get the default image field to render (`field_image`) - it just renders the url of the image. So I'm almost there but definitely missing something fundamental. Help please?

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const BlogPage = ({data}) => ( 
  <div> 
    <h1>Know What Grinds My Gears?</h1> 
    { data.allNodeArticle.edges.map(
      (
        { node }) => ( 

          <div> 
#the next Img line doesn't work (renders nothing)
            <Img fluid={ node.relationships.field_image.uri.url } /> 
            <h3> { node.title } </h3>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.body.summary }} />
            <Link to= { node.id } >read</Link>
#the next <figure> line doesn't work (renders correct url to image file)
            <figure> { node.relationships.field_image.uri.url }</figure>
         </div>

        )
      )
    } 
  </div> 
) 

export default BlogPage
export const query = graphql`
  query allNodeArticle {
    allNodeArticle { 
    edges { 
      node { 
        id
        title
        body { 
          value
          format
          processed
          summary
        }
        relationships {
          field_image {
            uri {
              value
              url
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
  `
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `node.relationships.field_image.uri.url` a valid url ? Can you for example use it as an `<img>`'s href attribute ?

Comment: thanks for your comment. `node.relationships.field_image.uri.url` gives me this `/sites/default/files/images/photo1.jpg` which is correct. I need to somehow prepend it with `../path-to-my-drupal-site` to correctly pull the image but I set the path in the `gatsby-config.js` so I still think I'm just not accessing it properly through GraphQL...?

Answer (score 1):

The way we manage this is by having on the GraphQL of the node image:

```
    field_image {
      relationships {
        field_media_image {
          localFile {
            publicURL
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 520 maxHeight: 520, cropFocus: CENTER) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And then using it as

```
    <Img
      fluid={
          data.nodePage.relationships.field_image.relationships.field_media_image.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid
        }
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @jmolivas. I'm embarking on this journey based in large part on the talk you gave at BadCamp this year. I do not have those options available to me in GraphQL. I cannot start with `field_image` and if I drill down through `allNodeArticle/edges/node/relationships/field_image` then the only option I have is `node__article`, not field_media_image`? I wonder if I don't have a required dependency? I'm on the Gatsby Starter Default and using `gatsby-image`? Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: sorry I goofed the backticks in the above comment. I'm locked out of edits now... =/

Comment: @TristanTheKnightAway I am planning to release a Drupal distribution and a Gatsby starter next week keep in touch.

Comment: @TristanTheKnightAway are you using core media module or the contrib one?

Comment: @TristanTheKnightAway be aware this GraphQL fragment `GatsbyImageSharpFluid`  will not work on the GraphiQL tool.

Comment: Cool! I look forward to your D8 distro for Gatsby. I am using core Drupal straight out of the box, so I guess the core media module. I thought it would be better to stay vanilla to start. Yes, I've read I cannot use `GatsbySharpFluid` in GraphQL but I cannot see the field `childImageSharp` as an option under `localfile` anyway (perhaps this is because one cannot use `GatsbySharpFluid` there?) I also cannot find `field_media_image` as an option. Maybe if I used the contrib media module instead? I'm eager to see your release. Gatsby is super fun to work with.

Comment: I'm almost there - I can query my node images and see them created in `/public` but I can't render them. Your code example was helpful in mapping out my query, thank you. Did you ever release your Drupal distro and Gatsby starter?

Comment: I found your blog series. This is awesome, THANK YOU for opening these up to the community https://weknowinc.com/blog/improving-drupal-and-gatsby-integration-drupal-modules